# Python PIL library not working image.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to debug this script in python from PIL import Image, ImageChops, ImageOps

I've searched all over the problem seems to be "image.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)" here. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks

```
image = Image.open(f_in)
print "got here"
image.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
print "cannot get here"
image_size = image.size
if pad:
    thumb = image.crop( (0, 0, size[0], size[1]) )

    offset_x = max( (size[0] - image_size[0]) / 2, 0 )
    offset_y = max( (size[1] - image_size[1]) / 2, 0 )

    thumb = ImageChops.offset(thumb, offset_x, offset_y)

else:
    thumb = ImageOps.fit(image, size, Image.ANTIALIAS, (0.5, 0.5))

thumb.save(f_out)
```

**EDIT**
Thanks for the quick answer Mark. I figured it out.

I had to:

```
pip uninstall PIL
sudo apt-get install libjpeg8-dev 
pip install PIL
```

I didn't have libjpeg installed. Not sure why I didn't get an error.

Comment: What is the problem you're actually observing?

Comment: Sorry. The problem is the code stops at image.thumbnail. I did figure it out. I had to uninstall PIL, sudo apt-get install libjpeg8-dev, and then reinstall PIL. And it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If the program never gets to the line "cannot get here" then the problem is that `thumbnail` is throwing an exception. You didn't mention that in the question though, it should have generated an error.

PIL uses lazy image loading - in the `open` call it might open the file, but it doesn't actually try to read the whole thing in. If your file is corrupt or in the wrong format it will fail once you try to do something with the image, as `thumbnail` is doing.